# Selenium IDE locator to get background-image attribute in div tag

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium IDE. I need to locate an element which does look like this:

```
<div style="background-image:url('http://www.example.com/img.png');">...</div>
```

Please suggest xpath/css path to be used for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below xpath:

```
//div[contains(@style,'http://www.example.com/img.png')]
```

It will select the `div` element whose `style` attribute contains the text `http://www.example.com/img.png`.

### EDIT

As per your requirement, in case you want to fetch specific image links, you can use the above xpath like this:

```
(//div[contains(@style,'example.com/img.png')])[1]
```

This will locate the first `div` element in the chronological order of DOM representation with `style` that contains `example.com/img.png`. Simlarly, if you want to locate the second `div` element then just replace `[1]` with `[2]`, if third then replace with `[3]` and so on.

### EDIT 2

- If you want to fetch `div` element (that has the `background-image: url("/images/smart_pattern/event.png");"` as part of its `style` attribute) for **PBX rule**, please use the below xpath:

  `//span[.='PBX rule']/following::div[1]`

  **OR**

  `//span[.='PBX rule']/following::div[contains(@style,'images/smart_pattern')]`
- Similarly, If you want to fetch `div` element (that has the `background-image: url("/images/smart_pattern/event.png");"` as part of its `style` attribute) for **Wan test**, please use the below xpath:

  `//span[.='Wan test']/following::div[1]`

  **OR**

  `//span[.='Wan test']/following::div[contains(@style,'images/smart_pattern')]`

Comment: thanks Subh, I am able to locate the element now, but one more problem, I am having same <div> tag, having same image link used at a couple of other places on the same web page.                               <div style="background-image:url('http://www.example.com/img.png');">...</div>.........<some other tags> ......... <div style="background-image:url('http://www.example.com/img.png');">...</div>   .........<some other tags>........  <div style="background-image:url('http://www.example.com/img.png');">...</div>                      Is there a way to identify each <div> tag separately ?

Comment: @Avinash: Please check my response in answer above under **EDIT** header. Hope that helps you out.!

Comment: thanks again Subh, but Selenium is not able to locate the expected element. Are you sure about the usage of [1], [2]... ? Is there any other way to differentiate tags having all the attributes same ?

Comment: Yes.. I am pretty sure about it.. I have edited my answer again above.. I guess the text was little off. Please check again and let me know.. If it still doesn't work, please upload a screenshot of the inspected elements using Firepath in [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and add the link here. It will be easier to resolve your issue then.

Comment: Sorry Subh, It didn't worked. I have uploaded the required screenshot of inspected element.                                                                                 Link: http://i.imgur.com/kQAPbas.png

Comment: Parent <div> tag is having id attribute, but it is dynamically changing each time the page is refreshed, so can't use it.

Comment: Please check the answer under **EDIT 2** now. Let me know if it works

Comment: @Avinash: Glad it worked out for you.. :) Please accept the answer so that others who face similar kind of issue will refer directly to this.. :)